# How can I deep search a Python list?

Tags: python, search, arraylist

I want to deep search in a list in Python. For example, I want to know that 5 is in `my_list` or not.

```
my_list = [2, [3, 4, [2, 3]], 1, [4, [5]]]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of lists, you can use this approach

```
>>> l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7], [8,9]]
>>> [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> 5 in [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
True
```

Which first flattens the list and the searches through it using O(n).

If your list looks like in your example, I can't think of another way to
do it than using for-loops...

Comment: This only works if you're flattening exactly one level of lists, and each element is guaranteed to also be iterable and not a possible match for the search. That being the case, `5 in itertools.chain.from_iterable(l)` is probably a bit clearer than the list comprehension, and certainly a bit faster (since it doesn't build the full list that will only be used for one single search).

Comment: that was what I said (or intended to say :-) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: Note that the comments on the accepted answer to that question claim that `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l)` is faster than the list comprehensions. The fact that you don't actually *need* a list to do a search (`in` works fine on any iterable) only compounds that.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure a quick way to do this with multi-levels of nests, but a recursive algorithm like this would do the trick:

```
def nestedSearch(nested, v):
    for element in nested:
        if isinstance(element, list):
            if nestedSearch(element, v):
                return True
        elif element == v:
            return True
    return False
```

You also might look at this for flattening multi-nested lists:

[Recursive generator for flattening nested lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377208/recursive-generator-for-flattening-nested-lists)

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the [`flatten` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377208/recursive-generator-for-flattening-nested-lists) (think of it as a recursive version of `itertools.chain`) with Python's standard `in` operator (which, on generators, does a linear search) to get this:

```
>>> def flatten(nested):
    try:
        for sublist in nested:
            for element in flatten(sublist):
                yield element
    except TypeError:
        yield nested


>>> my_list = [2, [3, 4, [2, 3]], 1, [4, [5]]]
>>> 5 in flatten(my_list)
True
```

Per the comments in the linked question, you will want to refine the `flatten` code if what you're searching for is iterable - eg, tuples will be flattened into the search just like lists, and searching for strings recurses until it hits Python's stack limit.

Answer (score 0):

One way for doing it:

```
def deapSearch(searchElement, searchList):
    for element in searchList:
        if element == searchElement:
            return True
        elif type(element) == type(list):
            found = deapSearch(searchElement, element)
            if found:
                return found
    return False
deapSearch(5, my_list)
True
deapSearch(4, my_list)
True
```

Not Beautiful but working.

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed to do this and needed a simple solution. So I am adding it as an a quick and dirty way to flatten/search a list (may not be a perfect solution but it worked for me).

```
>>> my_list = [2, [3, 4, [2, 3]], 1, [4, [5]]]
>>> str(5) in str(my_list) # returns True
>>> str(my_list).find(str(5)) # returns the index
```

Edit: Adding a regex solution as well. But if you have a more complicated case, then you might as well traverse the list.

```
>>> import re
>>> str(5) in re.findall('(?<=[,\[])([ a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)(?=[,\]])', str(my_list))
```

The regular expression essentially flattens the list, but won't work for special characters in list items.

Comment: `str(5) in str([1, [2, 15]]) # => True` Your method is wrong. You'd at least need a regex.

Answer (score -1):

if you only have a nested list with integers or chars, one way to solve this problem is to create a list  without all unwanted elements ( without '[' , ']' ... ) :

let's say we have a nested list with chars :

```
>>> nested = [[[[['F', 'B'], 'G'], ['D', 'A']], 'C'], 'E']
>>> string = str(nested)
>>> string = string.replace('[','',len(string))
>>> string = string.replace(']','',len(string))
>>> string = string.replace("'","",len(string))
>>> string = string.replace(" ","",len(string))
>>> string = string.split(',')
```

it gives :

```
>>> print (string)
['F', 'B', 'G', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'E']
```

Now you can search easily without any loop :

```
>>> 'F' in string
True
```

Comment: one thing you must take in consideration is that an integer nested list is more expensive in memory than a simple string, and a recursive function is not the simplest way to deal with such a problem because of the iteration depth limit. The big advantage in using Python is that you can search in a string the same way you search in a list