# Python nested list recursion search

Tags: python, list, recursion

Given a nested list L (such that each element of L is either an integer, or a list, which may itself
contain integers, or lists, which may in turn.... etc) return True i s is in L.

```
search([1, [2, 3], 4, [5, [6 , [], [8, 9]], 10]], 8)
```

should return True.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def search (L,s):
"""(list, anytype) _> Bool
Returns true iff s is present in L
"""
if L:
    if L[0] == s:
        return True
    else:
        return search (L[1:], s)
else:
    return False
```

This current code works for a list if it isn't nested, or if it is nested like so (the nested element is the last element):

```
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]
```

But not for the following:

```
[1, 2, [3, 4], 5]
```

How can I change my code so that it works for a nested list? with the nested element being anywhere in the list not strictly the last element?

Appreciate any help!

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to specify that it needs to be recursive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I deep search a Python list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292893/how-can-i-deep-search-a-python-list)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can squeeze your entire code like this

```
def search(current_item, number):
    if current_item == number: return True
    return isinstance(current_item, list) \
        and any(search(item, number) for item in current_item)
```

You can test it like this

```
for i in range(12):
    print i, search([1, [2, 3], 4, [5, [6 , [], [8, 9]], 10]], i)
```

**Output**

```
0 False
1 True
2 True
3 True
4 True
5 True
6 True
7 False
8 True
9 True
10 True
11 False
```

The logic is like this,

1. If the `current_item` is equal to the number we are looking for, return `True`.
2. If the `current_item` is not an instance of list, then it is a number in this case. If it is a number and it does not equal to `number` we should return `False`.
3. If the `current_item` is a list, then go through each and every element of it and check if any of the elements has `number`. `any` returns immediately after getting the first `True` value.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to specify I need to use recursion.

Comment: This *does* use recursion - see the recursive call to `search` on the last line.

Comment: could you explain the last 2 lines of your code? I understand `isinstance` and `any` but I am not exactly sure what they do when put together like that

Comment: @NickGong Please check my answer now. I have added basic explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't matter where the item is in the list something like this should work

```
def unpack(iterable):
   result = []
   for x in iterable:
      if hasattr(x, '__iter__'):
         result.extend(unpack(x))
      else:
         result.append(x)
   return result

 >>> unpack([1,2,3,[4,5,6],7,[8,[9,10],11,]])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Comment: This is a good algorithm to have in your commonly used tools. It's too bad the `itertools flatten` recipe doesn't have something like this. Your algorithm might be better as a generator since the list it unpacks could be very large.

Comment: very interesting, it looks pretty good to me, I would keep this in mind for future reference. But for this exercise I was required to set parameter like that and use recursion. Thank you though!