# how to extract values from python sublists

Tags: python, list, nested

```
data_sets = [
    ['O'],
    ['X'],
    # These data sets put Sheet A in all possible locations and orientations
    # Data sets 2 - 9
    ['O', ['Sheet A', 'Location 1', 'Upright']],
    ['O', ['Sheet A', 'Location 2', 'Upright']],
    ['O', ['Sheet A', 'Location 3', 'Upright']],
    ['O', ['Sheet A', 'Location 4', 'Upright']],
    ['O', ['Sheet A', 'Location 1', 'Upside down']],
    ['O', ['Sheet A', 'Location 2', 'Upside down']],
    ['O', ['Sheet A', 'Location 3', 'Upside down']],
    ['O', ['Sheet A', 'Location 4', 'Upside down']]
    ]

for each in data_sets:
    if 'Sheet A' in each:
        print('1')
```

when i run this, it doesn't print anything because i dont think its going through all the sublists. how can i get this to work?

Comment: You need to first check the length of your sublist then check for 'Sheet A' in possible sublists.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
import itertools
for each in data_sets:
    if "Sheet A" in itertools.chain.from_iterable(eeach):
        print("1")

1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/KvM1/0)

Comment: Does the search look into comments? I would want to find this under "How to check items if in (inside) nested lists inside a list". Great tool, works.

Comment: I believe the interable(eeach) is a typo. For me, similar works with interable(each), exactly as in the "for"-line.

Answer (score 1):

`in` is not recursive. It tries to find the item in the list itself. If the item is a `list`, `in` won't go down in the list to look for the string.

In your case, you could

- check if the list has at least 2 items
- perform `in` on the second item

like this:

```
for each in data_sets:
    if len(each)>1 and 'Sheet A' in each[1]:
        print('1')
```

of course if the structure is more complex/not fixed, you have to use a recursive approach which tests item type, like this: [Python nested list recursion search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662543/python-nested-list-recursion-search)

Answer (score 1):

```
def listChecker(list_elems):
   for list_elem in list_elems:
      if "Sheet A" in list_elem:
         print "1"
      if any(isinstance(elem, list)  for elem in list_elem):
         listChecker(list_elem)

listChecker(data_sets)
```

you can also use this function. It will be helpful to print 1 in all cases of nested lists. Just pass your list object to this function.

Comment: I was going to add this, if you didn't

Answer (score 0):

you can also check it by `count`.

```
for each in data_sets:
    if len(each)>1 and each[1].count("Sheet A"):
        print('1')
```

- `len(each)>1` checks the number of list item.
- `each[1]` is the second sublist of your given list. and `.count("Sheet A")` returns occurrence number of `Sheet A`.