# How to flatten a nested list in python?

Tags: python

How can I convert:

```
THIS = \
['logging',
 ['logging', 'loggers',
  ['logging', 'loggers', 'MYAPP',
   ['logging', 'loggers', 'MYAPP', '-handlers'],
   ['logging', 'loggers', 'MYAPP', 'propagate']
  ]
 ],
 ['logging', 'version']
]
```

into:

```
THAT = [
    ['logging'],
    ['logging', 'version'],
    ['logging', 'loggers'],
    ['logging', 'loggers', 'MYAPP'],
    ['logging', 'loggers', 'MYAPP', '-handlers'],
    ['logging', 'loggers', 'MYAPP', 'propagate']
]
```

in python (it doesn't need to be sorted, just flattened)?

I've tried lots of things but can't find how to solve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python), especially [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/406822/1535629).

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377208/recursive-generator-for-flattening-nested-lists?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved with recursive generator

```
def flatten(items):
    non_list_items = []

    for item in items:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            for inner_item in flatten(item):
                yield inner_item
        else:
            non_list_items.append(item)

    yield non_list_items
```

Testing against your input:

```
from pprint import pprint

>>> pprint(sorted(flatten(THIS)))
[['logging'],
 ['logging', 'loggers'],
 ['logging', 'loggers', 'MYAPP'],
 ['logging', 'loggers', 'MYAPP', '-handlers'],
 ['logging', 'loggers', 'MYAPP', 'propagate'],
 ['logging', 'version']]
```

Comment: Thanks I've been trying for ages to get this

Answer (score 2):

This is where a recursive function really shines:

```
def flatten(myList):
  def inner(current, acc):
    items = []
    for x in myList:
      if isinstance(x, list):
        acc.extend(inner(x, []))
      else:
        items.append(x)
    acc.extend(items)
    return acc

  return inner(myList, [])
```

which I believe should do the trick.