# Recursively counting occurrences in a nested list of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, nested-lists, flatten

I'm finally getting around to recursion in Python and trying to count the number of occurrences of a target number in a `list`. However, I'm running into issues with counting occurrences in a nested `list` of numbers.

For example

```
def count(lst, target):

    if lst == []:
        return 0
    if lst[0] == target:
        return 1 + count(lst[1:], target)
    else:
        return 0 + count(lst[1:], target)
```

Output

`>>> count( [1,2,3,[4,5,5],[[5,2,1],4,5],[3]], 1 )`

`Output: 1`

`Expected output: 2`

Is there an easy way to flatten nested-lists in Python? Or a simple way for me to account for the fact that there is a nested-list in my code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377208/recursive-generator-for-flattening-nested-lists?rq=1 This might be of help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def count(lst, target):
    n = 0
    for i in lst:
        if i == target:
            n += 1
        elif type(i) is list:
            n += count(i, target)
    return n
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need an extra case to deal with `lst[0]` being a sublist, like:

```
def count(lst, target):

    if lst == []:
        return 0
    if lst[0] == target:
        return 1 + count(lst[1:], target)
    # If first element is a list, descend into it to count within it,
    #    and continue with counts of remaining elements
    elif type(lst[0]) == list:
        return count(lst[0], target) + count(lst[1:], target)
    else:
        return 0 + count(lst[1:], target)
```