# How to extend a multi-dimensional list and keep order in Python

Tags: python

I got a list `[1, [2, [3, [4, [5, [6, [7], 6], 5], 4], 3], 2], 1]` and I wanna convert it to a single-dimensional list as the same order as 
it defined   `i.e [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]`

here is my code, but it is actually not meet my request

```
list_1 = [1, [2, [3, [4, [5, [6, [7], 6], 5], 4], 3], 2], 1]

def my_solution(lst):
    for index, value in enumerate(lst):
        if isinstance(value, list):

            my_solution(value)

            lst.extend(value)
            del(lst[index])
    return lst


print(my_solution(list_1))
```

the output is `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7]`

Comment: Related reading: [Recursive generator for flattening nested lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11377208/953482)